# how to make a Dart Function that holds a container?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

i have alot of similar containers in my app that hold varied pieces of text.
I want to make a Dart Function that i can then use to return the container and the specify color and text height and width.

when I try to make the Dart Function:

```
Container MyContainer() {}
```

the MyContainer part is coming back with the error:
The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type, 'Container', is a potentially non-nullable type

I've looked at the docs but don't understand how the common fixes would be implemented into the function.

cheers

Comment: just make a class that extends `StatelessWidget`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

1.Use functions that return `Container`. For Example,

> ```
> Container MyContainer({required Color color, required String label, double width = 200, double height = 300}) {
>  return Container(
>     height: height,
>     width: width,
>     decoration: BoxDecoration(
>     color: color,
>     ),
>     child: Text(label),
>  );
> }
> ```

But that's not a correct way to create a `Reusable Widget`.
The optimal way is:

2. Extract a `custom StatelessWidget class` for that widget. Like this.

> ```
> class MyContainer extends StatelessWidget {
>   const MyContainer({Key? key, this.width = 200, this.height = 300, required this.label, required this.color}) : super(key: key);
>   final double width;
>   final double height;
>   final String label;
>   final Color color;
>   @override
>   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
>     return Container(
>       width: width,
>       height: height,
>       decoration: BoxDecoration(
>         color: color,
>       ),
>       child: Text(label),
>     );
>   }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Just create a class extending `StatelessWidget` like this :

```
class MyCustomContainer extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyCustomContainer({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      // Do what you want
    );
  }
}
```

Or you can also do it quickly as a getter `Widget` inside another class

```
Widget myCustomContainer() {
    return Container(
      // Do what you want
    );
  }
```

And just call it inside your tree in `build()`